# Why do I have 3 HVAC professionals telling me 3 different things about heat gain/heat loss?

Tags: hvac, heating, cooling

I sent the same set of house drawings to 3 different firms that size HVAC equipment. They each sent back signed designs. Here are the results:

Firm 1: 65k BTU/h Heat Loss – 45k BTU/h Heat Gain

Firm 2: 53K BTU/h Heat Loss - 56k BTU/h Heat Gain

Firm 3: 61K BUT/h Heat Loss – 29K BTU/h Heat Gain

How can these be so different? Are these "Within error"? I don't have a sense for the typical error margin here. Any guidance here would help.

Comment: Those are actually pretty consistent considering how complicated it can be calculating thermodynamics in a system with several unknowns. In any field there's also a lot of room in human interpretations of the data; some technicians will feel a given rule or guideline is too strict, others will think it's not strict enough...

Comment: I would ask for the data (spreadsheet format) they used for the final numbers. For the heating numbers, I think they are close enough, but the cooling numbers are far apart, and depending on your type of summer, a wrong choice could make you miserable for a few weeks. That warrants a closer look.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In an ideal world, the numbers would really be based on your actual house construction and detailing.

In my world I have a spreadsheet that details the thermal characteristics and area of every part of my (non-traditionally constructed, so I have reason to mistrust usual assumptions) house and run my own calculations off that. I do sanity checks by looking at both average temperature and degree-day data to make sure that they appear to be in line with each other. I get results that have appeared to work correctly so I trust the process, and use it to look at various tradeoffs (how much would a somewhat more efficient but far more expensive HRV or ERV actually save me? Is 6" more insulation in the attic ever going to pay for itself? etc.)

In most of the the HVAC world, they use a variety of "prescribed methods and manuals" and a bad (but understandable) habit of habitually oversizing "to be sure it's big enough" which often results in considerable inefficiency "because it's too big" - depending on the nature of the drawings you sent, they may also have to make assumptions about thermal details of construction, even if they know what size it is from the drawings - which they have their manuals and methods for, since the data is often slim. But that feeds back to "assume the worst and end up oversized usually" results in order to end up big enough in the worst case.

So I expect your variation in results may have to do with variation in what assumptions were made, or rules of thumb (or computer modeling methods) applied.

Comment: It's also possible that they adjusted numbers up or down to match the sizes of the particular brand(s) of equipment they sell so you could get an "exact match".

Comment: @FreeMan: Or indeed whichever size they have the largest profit margin on. I **never** trust professionals for HVAC sizing. Almost all want to sell you something extremely oversized that will run at very low duty cycle and leave your home feeling like a swamp. If you have 3 professional opinions and have to go with one, always go with the lowest.

Comment: "The lowest" what?